# I want to create a simple import from one spresdsheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a simple import from one spreadsheet to another and also update data vice versa. Column to column mapping is required when copying and updating values from sheet2 to sheet1. can a VB script / Macro do this. I tried the following for copying but keep getting this error `Subscript out of range`.

```
Private Sub Import_Click()

'Assign variable name to Target workbook
    Var1 = "C:\ST Test\AAA.xlsm"
    Var1S = "Status Report"
    Var1R = "$A$3:$A$65536"
    'Assign variable name to Target range

    'Assign variable name to Source workbook
    Var2 = "C:\ST Test\BBB.xlsx"
    Var2S = "WORKPLAN"
    Var2R = "$A$8:$A$65536"

    'Open Source WorkBook
    Application.Workbooks.Open ("C:\ST Test\BBB.xlsx")


    'Copy from Source to Target
    Workbooks(Var2).Sheets(Var2S).Range(Var2R).EntireColumn.Copy _
    Destination:=Workbooks(Var1).Sheets(Var1S).Range(Var1R)

    'Close Source WorkBook wo/Save
    Workbooks(Var2).Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line gives the error? Also, are you copying data from one workbook to another, or one worksheet to another?

Comment: Workbooks(Var2).Sheets(Var2S).Range(Var2R).EntireColumn.Copy _
Destination:=Workbooks(Var1).Sheets(Var1S).Range(Var1R) gives me the error. I am trying to copy from one worksheet under one workbook to another worksheet under another workbook.

Answer (score 0):

When usuing the EntireColumn this will select a column based on where your selection is. So if you were going for a range that was not the entire column simply us Range(x).Select/Copy Destination:= Workbooks(y).Range(q)

Another way to look at an operation like this is to simply set the ranges equal to each other with will save time by not using the clipboard.

See this code:
Workbooks("test1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Workbooks("test1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5").Value = Workbooks("test.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5").Value

Comment: Senthanic4 --Thanks for the reply.  I tried using the following and still got the stack overflow warning. My problem is that I need to copy A3 from first sheet to be copied into A8 and so forth.    Workbooks(Var1).Worksheets(Var1S).Range("A3:A99").Value = Workbooks(Var2).Worksheets(Var2S).Range("A8:A104").Value

Comment: I mean to say it gives "subscript out of range" error

Comment: Private Sub Import_Click()

    Var1 = "C:\ST Test\AAA.xlsm"
    Var1S = "Status Report"
    Var1R = "$A$3:$A$65536"
    Var2 = "C:\ST Test\BBB.xlsx"
    Var2S = "WORKPLAN"
    Var2R = "$A$8:$A$65536"
    
    Application.Workbooks.Open (Var2)
        
      
    'Copy from Source to Target
   Workbooks(Var1).Worksheets(Var1S).Range("$A$3:$A$99").Value = Workbooks(Var2).Worksheets(Var2S).Range("$A$8:$A$104").Value

      Workbooks(Var2).Close False
End Sub

Comment: Yep try changing the variable names to
Var1 = "Status_Report_Draft.xlsm"
Var2 = "J62EAC WORKPLAN MASTER.xlsx"
and when opening the workbook make sure to use the path